# mat-checkbox is not working while using ng-template in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, ng-template

Im using Angular Slickgrid to display the data,in that I have noticed that the mat-checkbox is not working while using ng-template.

**Current Behavior:**

The checkbox is not working while using ng-template in some cases. As per the analysis the mat-checkbox checked class is not added in the DOM. Once inspect the element and added the missing class manually, then it is working fine.

**Code format:**

```
<**ng-container** ngTemplateOutlet]="booleanField" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{'fieldKey':fieldKey}"></**ng-container**>
```

**Template:**

```
<**ng-template** #booleanField let-fieldKey="fieldKey">

<**div**>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="matLabel" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{'fieldKey':fieldKey}">
</ng-container>

<**section** class="example-section">

<**mat-checkbox** id="{{'FLD_cspfm_webcommon_lookup_filter_'+filterSectionDetail['filterFields'][fieldKey]['rootPath']+'$$'+filterSectionDetail['filterFields'][fieldKey]['fieldName']+'_0_input'}}"
class="cs-margin-left-to-right" (change)="valueChange(fieldKey,$event, undefined, 0)"                [checked]="filterSectionDetail['filterFields'][fieldKey]['fieldValue'][0]"> true </**mat-checkbox**>

<**mat-checkbox** id="{{'FLD_cspfm_webcommon_lookup_filter_'+filterSectionDetail['filterFields'][fieldKey]['rootPath']+'$$'+filterSectionDetail['filterFields'][fieldKey]['fieldName']+'_1_input'}}"
class="cs-margin-left-to-right" (change)="valueChange(fieldKey,$event, undefined, 1)"               [checked]="filterSectionDetail['filterFields'][fieldKey]['fieldValue'][1]"> false </**mat-checkbox**>

</**section**>

</**div**>

</**ng-template**>
```

**Expected Behavior:**

The checkbox should be work in all cases while using ng-template.

**Software Version**

- Angular : 13.3.9
- TypeScript : 4.6.4
- Operating System : Windows 10
- Node : 14.18.3
- NPM : 6.14.8